# Is it correct to use Debugger.IsAttached to determinate the environment?

Tags: c#, development-environment, production-environment

I have only two environments: **development** and **production**. Would it be a good idea to use the next code to know if the application is running in one or another?

```
bool IsProduction()
{
   return !Debugger.IsAttached;
}
```

I read [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/235618/environment-aware-code) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343307/creating-c-sharp-winform-development-and-production-environments) but it seems to me discussions took a different way.

What about using an appSettings key?

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="Environment" value="Dev"/>
</appSettings>
```

What will happen if someone edit the config file? Should the code have a "double-check" mechanism? Should the value be encrypted or is it too much?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Your method says "if the debugger is attached then we are in production".  Are you in the habit of debugging only in production, and never in development? I am very confused by your code, and that alone is reason not to do this.

Comment: More generally, you should use the "is the debugger attached" method for *only one thing*: to see if the debugger is attached.

Comment: @EricLippert sorry, I was missing the ! operator.

Comment: OK, then reason it through logically.  Is the debugger *always* attached in development?  Is it *never* attached in production?  If those two things are true then your code is correct. If either is not then the code is sometimes wrong. What are the consequences of writing sometimes-wrong code?

Comment: @EricLippert Yes, those things are true. I will go that way for now. Thank you for your comments.

Comment: I'll never will get 50 rep..

Comment: The question to ask yourself here is: why do I care? What are you going to do in production that you don't do in development? What are you going to do in development that you don't do in production?  Suppose for example you say "I want to run the same computation twice in development, once using a fast algorithm and once using a slow algorithm, and verify that the results are the same, but in production I only want to run the fast algorithm". For something like that you'd use an assert, conditional compilation, or a conditional method. Say what you actually want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Debugger.IsAttached` will only return true if the process has a debugger attached independently of the build (runs under VS or has an external debugger attached).

If you want to diferentiate the environment based on the build type you can use the preprocessor directives to set a boolean, something like this:

```
#if DEBUG
bool isDebug = true;
#else
bool isDebug = false;
#endif
```

Comment: You can also use the `[Conditional("DEBUG")]` attribute ([MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute.aspx))

Answer (score 0):

The first method using Debugger.IsAttached is not going to work even in development unless you actually have the debugger attached to the process.

Configuration values is a proper approach and probably the best that I know of from a flexibility stand point. You can configure different environments and by using the transformation config files this will be updated during deployment automatically.

If you want more information about the config transformation method I can provide you some links

Answer (score 0):

**You should never assume that** `Debugger.IsAttached` **will not run in Production mode.** You would get into trouble as you can see that it will unlock developer mode functionalities in PROD mode, if you used code like the following:

```
if (Debugger.IsAttached())
{
    // Unlock Developer functionalities;
}
```